# Android : Does IntentService works request by request or concurrently

Tags: android, intentservice

I have my custom IntentService :

```
public class CustomService extends IntentService {
// some line of code here 
}
```

And I call `CustomService` from `BroadcastReceiver`  Because the length is not fix (base on how often `BroadcastReceiver` will be called, so calling `CustomService` sometimes will be overlap. It means one Service object still run when another begin to start.

My question is : when another `CustomService` object comes to play, it will wait until another has been done before it run. Or it will run concurrently with others. This point is important to me, because if they works together, I will meet some problems due to multithreads access same resource.

Thanks :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> It means one Service object still run when another begin to start.

No. There will be at most one instance of your `CustomService`.

> when another CustomService object comes to play, it will wait until another has been done before it run. Or it will run concurrently with others.

If we convert "another CustomService object" to "another `startService()` call", `IntentService` processes commands (`Intent` objects) one at a time. The `Intent` from your second `startService()` call will not be processed until `onHandleIntent()` completes its work with your first `Intent`.